# JS - Transform object to an object array with keys being part of array objects with util library

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

When writing lib/framework code API in js I often prefer this:

```
const definition = {
  foo: {
    someProp: 'foo-prop'
  },
  bar: {
    someProp: 'bar-prop'
  }
}
```

as an alternative to

```
const definition2 = [
{ name: 'foo', someProps:'foo-prop'},
{ name: 'bar', someProps:'bar-prop'}
]
```

as I find the former syntax friendly.

When processing the configuration I of course prefer array as shown in `definition2` so I end up with this transformation code:

```
const arrayDefinition = Object.entries(objDefinition)
    .map(([key, val]) => ({name: key, ...val}))
```

Is there a way how to reduce this boiler with a well known util library like`lodash` or `ramba` which would have function similar to this ?

```
const objToArray = obj => keyProp =>
    Object.entries(obj)
        .map(([key, val]) => ({[keyProp]: key, ...val}))
```

I prefer using existing libs to creating my own util functions.

Comment: As far as i am aware, there is no specific method in lodash-fp for this, so you would be replacing Javascript boilerplate for lodash, no improvement in my opinion. Of course, someone may have written a mixin that does this using lodash. https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide

Comment: I also didn't see anything ready built to use in ramda.

Comment: `map` function of `underscore` and `loadash` can be used for `object` as well (apart from `collection`) to achieve this.

Comment: @dev-null did you tried my answer of using `map` with object for your use case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a easier way by using **utility library** like `loadash` or `underscore` then here is a easy solution for you

```
_.map(obj, function(val, key) {
    return {
        name: key,
        someProp: val.someProp
    }
})
```

This code will work for both, `underscore.js` as well as `loadash`, because the `map` function there is meant for both, object and array.

Answer (score -1):

You could add a prototype to global `Object`

```js
Object.prototype.toArr = function(propName){ 
  return  Object.keys(this).map(key => Object.assign({[propName]:key}, this[key]));  
}

const definition = {
  foo: {
    someProp: 'foo-prop'
  },
  bar: {
    someProp: 'bar-prop'
  }
}

let arr = definition.toArr('name');

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, ' '))
```